# Mongoose date field - Set default to date.now + N days

Tags: javascript, mongoose

In a mongoose schema such as:

```js
var EventSchema = new Schema({
 title: {
  type: String,
  default: '',
  trim: true,
  required: 'Title cannot be blank'
 },
 description: {
  type: String,
  default: '',
  trim: true
 },
 start: {
  type: Date,
  default: Date.now,
  required: 'Must have start date - default value is the created date'
 },
 end: {
  type: Date,
  default: Date.now + 7 Days, // Date in one week from now
  required: 'Must have end date - default value is the created date + 1 week'
 },
 tasks: [{
  type: Schema.ObjectId,
  ref: 'Task'
 }]
});
```

On the line for the "end" field the default date should set to +7 days.  I can add presave hook and set it there, but wondering if theres a way to do this inline in the default field.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can add 7 days converted to milliseconds to current date like this

```
default: new Date(+new Date() + 7*24*60*60*1000)
```

or even like this

```
default: +new Date() + 7*24*60*60*1000
```

**UPDATE**

Please check the @laggingreflex comment below. You need to set function as default value:

```
default: () => new Date(+new Date() + 7*24*60*60*1000)
```

Comment: Excellent!  Works perfectly

Comment: This results in the same date(+ndays) **which was calculated *at the time* of running the application**. I.e. if your app has been running for more than n days, you'll be setting dates in the past! To correct this, it should be wrapped around in a function `default: function(){return +new Date() + 7*24*60*60*1000}`

Comment: why add `+` in front of `new Date()`

Comment: @ Gurbakhshish Singh  `+` converts to number instead of date object I think.

Comment: This code `+new Date()` have performance issues. I have fixed my own answer to avoid confusing people. This code creates Date instance each time been called. So It makes additional pressure to garbage collector. To avoid this, use `Date.now()`. `.now()` method is static for Data class and it just returns number value. So garbage collection should not have to trash created `Date` instances. Hope this helps, kind regards.

Comment: +new Date() + 7*24*60*60*1000 will not work when the year changes. 
current date 30-dec-2019 , when we add this line of code , it will not generate next year date

Comment: In a Mongoose schema for a date field, keep in mind that the default value is evaluated once when the schema is compiled. if you use Date.now() as a default value, multiple documents will share the same timestamp. Beacause of this, for unique vaules on "default" you need pass a function.

Answer (score 67):

```
default: () => Date.now() + 7*24*60*60*1000
```

This will be enough

Comment: From my end here... this date function return wrong date in my own case... the date is a week beyond todays now. so I refactor the code by using only 

`() => Date.now()`