# Add month to current date in mongoose schema's default date value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, date, mongoose

We have a mongoose schema like this:

```
var sampleSchema = new Schema({
    fieldABC: String,
    expireAfter1Month:{
        type: Date,
        default: new Date() + 1 month
    }
});
```

The default value of `expireAfter1Month` shall be set to a date value after a month.

I have got these:

- [Mongoose date field - Set default to date.now + N days](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29899208/2404470)
- [Set default date in Mongoose document to now + [some increment]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30524483/2404470)

How to add month to current date in mongoose schema's default date value?

Probably I can do like

```
default: +new Date() + 30*24*60*60*1000
```

However, I wonder if there is any better/optimized approach?

Comment: see the accepted answer for the second link? use `timeObject.setMonth(timeObject.getMonth() + 1);` instead?? perhaps? Don't worry about overflow ... adding a month to a date in december will result in a date in january ... of course ... what if you add a month to 31st january - that would result in 2 March, is that what you want?

Comment: @JaromandaX Will test that and let know. I want if it's 31st Jan then I need 2 March

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Building on the answer to one of the links you posted

i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30525690/5053002

```
var minuteFromNow = function(){
    var timeObject = new Date();
    timeObject.setTime(timeObject.getTime() + 1000 * 60);
    return timeObject;
};

new Schema({
    date: { type: Date, default: minuteFromNow }
})
```

If you want, for example, one month from 29th/30th/31st January to all be 28th February (29th in leap years of course), and one month from 31st March, May, August or October to be 30th April, June, September and November respectively, then you need a little more logic

Something like

```
function oneMonthFromNow() {
    var d = new Date();
    var targetMonth = d.getMonth() + 1;
    d.setMonth(targetMonth);
    if(d.getMonth() !== targetMonth % 12) {
        d.setDate(0); // last day of previous month
    }
    return d;
}
new Schema({
    date: { type: Date, default: oneMonthFromNow}
})
```

To illustrate how that would handle end of month, the following is the same code, except `d` is an arbitrary date passed in, rather than using `now` - to show how this will work

```js
function oneMonthFromNow(d) {
    var targetMonth = d.getMonth() + 1;
    d.setMonth(targetMonth);
    if(d.getMonth() !== targetMonth % 12) {
        d.setDate(0); // last day of previous month
    }
    return d;
}
console.log(oneMonthFromNow(new Date('2017-10-31T00:00:00Z'))); // 30 November
console.log(oneMonthFromNow(new Date('2017-11-30T00:00:00Z'))); // 30 December
console.log(oneMonthFromNow(new Date('2017-12-31T00:00:00Z'))); // 31 January
console.log(oneMonthFromNow(new Date('2018-01-31T00:00:00Z'))); // 28 February
console.log(oneMonthFromNow(new Date('2018-02-28T00:00:00Z'))); // 28 March
```

Your comment (added after I posted this answer :p) suggests one month from Jan 31 should be Mar 2, i.e. always just add 30 days, in that case your own suggestion

```
new Schema({
    date: { type: Date, default: +new Date() + 30*24*60*60*1000}
})
```

would be ideal

Comment: So often Date questions are poorly answered, it's a pleasant change to see a good one. :-)