# How to remove unverified user with Mongoose and TTL

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to remove users that have not verified their accounts during a certain period of time. An user can have a google account (through Google´s API) or register locally. I only care about the locals ones.

I have tried to do this with TTL without success, here is my User schema. Any idea what is wrong? So far I have not managed to remove them.

Thank you in advance.

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  local: {
    type: {
      email: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
      name: { type: String, required: true },
      password: { type: String, required: true },
      resetPasswordToken: String,
      resetPasswordExpires: Date,
      verificationToken: String,
      verificationExpires: Date,
      registrationConfirmed: Boolean
    },
    required: false
  },
  google: {
    id: String,
    name: String,
    email: String
  },
  accountType: String
});

userSchema.index(
  { 'local.verificationExpires': 1 },
  {
    expireAfterSeconds: 0,
    partialFilterExpression: { 'local.registrationConfirmed': false }
  }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I think your schema definition is not a valid mongoose schema.
I removed the local.type.

Also I gave the verificationExpires date a default date with a expiration of 3 minutes, you can change that value.

So the schema must be like this:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  local: new mongoose.Schema({
    email: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    resetPasswordToken: String,
    resetPasswordExpires: Date,
    verificationToken: String,
    verificationExpires: {
      type: Date,
      default: () => new Date(+new Date() + 3 * 60 * 1000) //3 minutes
    },
    registrationConfirmed: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  }),
  google: {
    id: String,
    name: String,
    email: String
  },
  accountType: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

Secondly, you can create the index on mongodb directly.

Here are the steps I could make it work:

1-) Remove the index related code in the user schema.

```
userSchema.index(
  { 'local.verificationExpires': 1 },
  {
    expireAfterSeconds: 0,
    partialFilterExpression: { 'local.registrationConfirmed': false }
  }
);
```

2-) Drop users collection (consider backup if you don't want to lose data)

3-) Create a users collection using some gui like MongoDB Compass.

4-) Create this index in mongodb.

```
db.users.createIndex(
    { 'local.verificationExpires': 1 },
    {
        expireAfterSeconds: 0,
        partialFilterExpression: { 'local.registrationConfirmed': false }
    }
)
```

This will output something like this:

```
{
    "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
    "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
    "numIndexesAfter" : 2,
    "ok" : 1
}
```

5-) I created 2 users like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5def4f0499dc104620a3310b"),
    "local" : {
        "registrationConfirmed" : false,
        "_id" : ObjectId("5def4f0499dc104620a3310c"),
        "email" : "user2@def.net",
        "name" : "user2",
        "password" : "123123",
        "verificationExpires" : ISODate("2019-12-10T10:56:40.884+03:00")
    },
    "__v" : 0
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5def4eff99dc104620a33109"),
    "local" : {
        "registrationConfirmed" : false,
        "_id" : ObjectId("5def4eff99dc104620a3310a"),
        "email" : "user1@def.net",
        "name" : "user1",
        "password" : "123123",
        "verificationExpires" : ISODate("2019-12-10T10:56:35.385+03:00")
    },
    "__v" : 0
}
```

6-) I manually set user1's registrationConfirmed to true:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5def4eff99dc104620a33109"),
    "local" : {
        "registrationConfirmed" : true,
        "_id" : ObjectId("5def4eff99dc104620a3310a"),
        "email" : "user1@def.net",
        "name" : "user1",
        "password" : "123123",
        "verificationExpires" : ISODate("2019-12-10T10:56:35.385+03:00")
    },
    "__v" : 0
}
```

7-) user2 is removed  after a few seconds when the verificationExpires passed.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I will try this if I do not find other solution but I would to explore other options. If that option is not supported by mongoose I think it would throw an error. On top of that, I have tried without that option (so I always remove the user even if it has validated the account) and still does not work. So it must be something else...

Comment: @JavierGuzman actually I tried this as a demo in my application, and it seems to work. So I suggest you try this answer first.

Comment: Hello again Suleyman! I have tried but it does not work.. When I create the user I set verificationExpires to Date.now() + 2 * 1000, so after 3 minutes or so the user should be removed but this does not happen. What do you get when you run getIndexes()?

Comment: @JavierGuzman  I think your schema must be corrected, I updated the answer to correct your schema. Also I tried this solution and it is working, so please carefully follow the exact steps I gave in answer.

Comment: Thanks! I will try when I arrive home. One question in the meantime, in the schema, why do you wrap the date in a new Date()? Is that really needed? Also you create the users using ISODate...So far my application also uses pure UTC milliseconds...When I create a new user the verificationExpires is set e.g. to "new Date() + 60 * 1000) so after 60 seconds. Do you think that could be the issue? Maybe internally MongoDB does not use UTC milliseconds when running TTL?

Comment: @JavierGuzman I got that info from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29899208/mongoose-date-field-set-default-to-date-now-n-days)

Comment: Hello Suleyman! I can confirm I have managed to make it work! You got it right. I have to say that there is no need to create manually the index, etc. the real problem was the time. It seems that this type of TTL index only works with ISODates. I was using Date.now() which returns milliseconds and I think you cannot compare that automatically so probably MongoDB internally was not getting the correct comparison result. I thought you could compare any type of dates...I give you the vote, thanks!